# How do I get my timer to activate when I press Space-Bar

Tags: timer, unity-game-engine, unityscript

My timer does not activate when I press spacebar, like it should. It appears on the screen and will not go down unless I press the spacebar many times in quick succession, then it goes down one second, which is odd.

```
   #pragma strict
var myTimer : float = 60.0;
var fontSize: int = 100;
public var guiSkin : GUISkin;
var spaceTrue : boolean = false;


function Start () {


}

function Update () {
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
        print("space key was pressed");
        spaceTrue = !spaceTrue;
}
if(myTimer > 0 && spaceTrue){
    myTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}



    //if(myTimer <= 0){
        //Debug.Log("Game Over");






    function OnGUI(){

GUI.skin = guiSkin;
    GUI.Label(new Rect(250,150,50,20),"" + myTimer.ToString("0"));
    //GUI.Label(new Rect(250,150,50,20),"" + myTimer.ToString("0"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay how about doing this

```
var spaceTrue:bool = false;

Update(){

if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
        print("space key was pressed");
        spaceTrue = !spaceTrue;

}

if(myTimer>0 && spaceTrue)
 myTimer-=Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Doing it the other way seemed like the player has to keep holding or pressing the button because the Update is going to be called every frame so if the player is not pressing the space button it won't go into that condition, I think. This way the Timer checks the boolean instead. So if spaceTrue is true then that means player pressed the button. If they hit again make false,etc

Comment: I changed the bool, to boolean because it was not recognizing it but it still doesnt work. The console doesnt give me any errors but it is just a 60 on my scene. Hitting spacebar only changes the inspector box because the variable is public. So I know it is half working, the timer just isnt starting. I feel like it has t odo with the Time.deltaTime and how it isnt starting at the beginning of the scene load up. What do you think?

Comment: Haha I got it to work. I dont know why it wasnt working before but now it does. I updated my code on the main post to the working one